# Pandas: how do I merge logfile wrapped lines together into the last column of the preceding line/row?

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, logging

I've got the following sample log file:

```
Timestamp : Severity : Message
2020-03-08 : INFO : First line.
2020-03-08 : INFO : child process stdout:
One
Two
Three
2020-03-08 : INFO : Last line.
```

NOTE: The original one has much more columns and several punctuation characters.

The service generating this log spawns child processes that might end up dumping their stdout (i.e. with undefined formatting) into the parent logs.

If I try to import it in Pandas, I get the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('mini_sample.txt', sep=' : ', engine='python')

    Timestamp Severity                Message
0  2020-03-08     INFO            First line.
1  2020-03-08     INFO  child process stdout:
2         One     None                   None
3         Two     None                   None
4       Three     None                   None
5  2020-03-08     INFO             Last line.
```

Although, I'd like to get something like this:

```
    Timestamp Severity                Message            Extra
0  2020-03-08     INFO            First line.             None
1  2020-03-08     INFO  child process stdout:  One\nTwo\nThree
2  2020-03-08     INFO             Last line.             None
```

So, the lines that don't respect the main log's formatting (i.e. coming from a child process' stdout/stderr) end up into an additional column (i.e. 'Extra') of the previous row.

Moreover, they should keep their original formatting (i.e. newline characters) so I can read it easily when printed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#test non datetimes in first column Timestamp
m = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], errors='coerce').notna()
#get new column by Timestamp with no datetimes
df['Extra'] = df['Timestamp'].mask(m)
#replace Timestamp to misisng values if no datetimes
df['Timestamp'] = df['Timestamp'].where(m)
#aggregate first values by first 3 columns and join by Extra column
df = df.groupby(m.cumsum()).agg({'Timestamp':'first', 
                                 'Severity':'first', 
                                 'Message':'first',
                                 'Extra': lambda x: '\n'.join(x.dropna())})
print (df)
            Timestamp Severity                Message            Extra
Timestamp                                                             
1          2020-03-08     INFO            First line.                 
2          2020-03-08     INFO  child process stdout:  One\nTwo\nThree
3          2020-03-08     INFO             Last line.
```

Comment: You have not only provided a working solution, but also a mix of methods that are helping me getting a better understanding of how to use them. I'd like to provide a summary just to confirm I've got it right. 1) Create a boolean masks to track where valid timestamps are; 2) duplicate the `Timestamp` column, by keeping ony the _not-timestamp_ values; 3) get rid of the _no-timestamp_ values in the `Timestamp` column; 4) aggregation: `first` value of each group of rows for all the columns but the `Extra`, which is aggregated by string concatenation. Is that right?

Comment: Could you please provide an explanation of `df.groupby(m.cumsum())`? I've always seen a column name in there. If I look at the docs for [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html?highlight=groupby#pandas-dataframe-groupby), it says that _"If a dict or Series is passed, the Series or dict VALUES will be used to determine the groups"_. Is this what you are doing? Is this just a group number or it has to match the `df.index` of the resulting dataframe?

Comment: I've noticed the empty cells in the `Extra` column contains empty strings. Is there any way we can replace them with `NaN` during the above process, or should I just introduce an additional step like `df['Extra'] = df['Extra'].replace(r'', np.nan)`?

Comment: @muxevola - First comment - nice, agree. Second comment - yop, obviously is groupby by column name like `df.groupby('col')`, but is possible pass also `Series` like `df.groupby(df['col'])` or like here `df.groupby(m.cumsum())`. It working nice, because `m.index` is same like `g.index`. Third comment - yes, solution is correct, is necessary replace for missing values